# ReferenceError: term is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that only allows the user to click search - I added a section to prevent them from sending empty requests but I seem to have messed up when combining that with my existing code. Now when I click search in the console logs I see the error:

```
ReferenceError: term is not defined
data: { 's' : term },
---------^
```

Below is the code for my page. How can I fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
    enter code here
        var empty = false;
        $('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});

    $("#btnSearch").click(function(event) {
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var term = $("#urlField").val();
    perlExecute(term);
 });

function perlExecute(url){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cgi-bin/domain-.pl',
        data: { 's' : term },
        success: function(res) {
        $("#result").text(res);
        },
        error: function() {alert("did not work");}
    });
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." id="urlField">
    <div class='actions'>
   <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
<div id="result"></div>
<p id="content">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed in `term` as a parameter, but you renamed it to `url`. Use `{'s':url}` instead. `term` is scoped to the document ready function, so it does not exist in the `perlExecute` scope.